# find parent element by selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I want to find a parent element of a text and get the deleted text through several operations
This is also the code

```
qr=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')[1].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.lastChild.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes[0].children[1].children[0].lastChild.lastChild.textContent
print(qr)
```

Comment: I do not receive an error when I do this with execut-script but I do not receive any

Comment: this approach looks way to complicated. why not showing us what you want to archive with a valid link and more code?

Comment: This is my Instagram robot code, and due to changing all the values ​​I wanted, I had to use this method, and the output is a text.